# Using Example Code I found to calculate locations within 10 miles of Latitude/Longitude

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I found this code:

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `members` HAVING `distance`<=’10’ ORDER BY `distance` ASC

on this website: http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/
```

That looks like it should work, but I am getting nothing but errors. Here is the structure of my table:

```
Postal_Code varchar(25)
Place_Name  varchar(255)
State   varchar(255)
State_Abbreviation  varchar(2)
County  varchar(255)
Latitude    float
Longitude   float
```

So I renamed the fields, but not sure I did it the right way:

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(("-97.079" – Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zipfields` HAVING `distance`<=’10’ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

I chose a random Lat/Long to put in place of $lat and $lon in the code.

But nothing I am trying works. The table name is zipfields.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,
-Richard

------ UPDATES ---------

Okay, I ran the suggestion below from @Pathik_Vejani and it did get me results:

this code:

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(("-97.079" - Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zipfields` HAVING distance<='10' ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Does list items as 'distance'... but I see an error in phpMyAdmin when I run it. It says this:

```
This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

Also, the list is like this:

```
distance Ascending
0.00014448859333250288
6.617290577027735
7.585634557261859
7.92136532629013
7.981747924484232
8.65536684196846
```

How do I get the results to list the unique records in that table that fall inside that distance, instead of showing me the distances?

Example, in that table I also have a auto_increment primary key, so I would like it to list all of those id's that fall in that distance. The name of that field is: "zfid"

So is there a way to have it select `zfid` where the longitudes/latitudes I give it are inside of the 10 miles away?

I don't need the distances, I just need the list of those records.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: I get this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'â€“ Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `z' at line 1

Comment: can you try my answer?

Comment: I did. :) I updated my original question.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Use a minus sign `-`, not an en-dash `â€“` `–`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some special characters, so it is not working I think, use this:

```
    SELECT zfid,
           ((ACOS(SIN("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(("-97.079" - Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`
    FROM `zipfields`
    HAVING `distance`<='10'
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

change this **HAVING distance<=’10’** to **HAVING distance<='10'** and also change this **– Longitude** to **- Longitude**

Comment: This did put some results... but i don't have room here, so please check the edits I'll make on the original question, I'll put it in the bottom of the original post.

Comment: change this `– Longitude` to `- Longitude` and try

Comment: I did do that. it did show me a list of "distance". I updated the original question, can you please see that?

Comment: do you want all the records?

Comment: I got it:

    SELECT `zfid`, ((ACOS(SIN("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS("35.4262" * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(("-97.079" - Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zipfields` HAVING distance<='10' ORDER BY `zfid` ASC